# How to reload a post page editor after published?

Tags: posts

I have a unique website type that only requires 10-20 seconds to make a new post. I want my WordPress site to reload the editor page automatically after a new post has been published hence I don't need to click "Add New" button in order to load blank post editor page.

Answer (score 0):

In no way I recommend to do that, as it will decrease the flexibility. 
However, if you have very rarest occasion and really need what you say, then put this code in `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'newpost_redirect', 99);
function newpost_redirect() {
    if ( isset($_POST['original_publish']) && "Publish"==$_POST['original_publish']){ 
        wp_redirect(admin_url('post-new.php') , 302 ); exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that using the `redirect_post_location` (see [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/redirect_post_location/)) hook would be a better way - it fires only in this particular context (when post gets redirected after being edited - [see code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-admin/includes/post.php#L1870)).

```
add_filter('redirect_post_location', 'redirect_after_post_update', 10, 2 );
function redirect_after_post_update( $location, $post_id ) {

    // make sure we're in dashboard
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        return $location;
    }

    // check if post was published, not updated
    if ( ! isset( $_POST[ 'publish' ] ) ) {
        return $location;
    }

    $new_post_sceen = get_admin_url( '', 'post-new.php');

    if ( ! empty( $new_post_sceen ) ) {
        return $new_post_sceen;
    }

    return $location;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use JS code to achieve this functionality.

```
add_action('admin_footer-post-new.php', 'reload_editor_after_publish');

function reload_editor_after_publish() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $(document).on('publish-post', function() {
                location.reload(true);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```